# Sonarqube Elastisearch exited unexpectedly with exit code 78

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to set up Sonarqube on Azure AKS using the docs https://devpress.csdn.net/k8s/62ebfc9719c509286f415f8c.html

After following the steps in the guide I can query a pod 'sonarqube' which returns:

```
Defaulted container "sonarqube" out of: sonarqube, wait-for-db (init), init-sysctl (init)
2024.02.02 21:09:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2024.02.02 21:09:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:36911]
2024.02.02 21:09:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=./bin/elasticsearch -Dcli.libs=lib/tools/server-cli -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib/*:/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib/cli-launcher/* org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
2024.02.02 21:09:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2024.02.02 21:09:10 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[8.11.0], pid[79], build[tar/d9ec3fa628c7b0ba3d25692e277ba26814820b20/2023-11-04T10:04:57.184859352Z], OS[Linux/5.15.0-1053-azure/amd64], JVM[Eclipse Adoptium/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/17.0.10/17.0.10+7]
2024.02.02 21:09:10 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM home [/opt/java/openjdk], using bundled JDK [false]
2024.02.02 21:09:10 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=org.elasticsearch.preallocate, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp, -XX:ErrorFile=/opt/sonarqube/logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:disable, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djna.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Dcom.redhat.fips=false, -Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=true, -Xmx2G, -Xms2G, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1073741824, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.distribution.type=tar, --module-path=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib, --add-modules=jdk.net, --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH, -Djdk.module.main=org.elasticsearch.server]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-core]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [old-lucene-versions]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [rest-root]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-redact]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-security]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [aggregations]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [apm]
root@MSI:/home/markee/security# kubectl logs sonarqube-sonarqube-0 -n sonarqube
Defaulted container "sonarqube" out of: sonarqube, wait-for-db (init), init-sysctl (init)
2024.02.02 21:09:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2024.02.02 21:09:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:36911]
2024.02.02 21:09:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=./bin/elasticsearch -Dcli.libs=lib/tools/server-cli -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib/*:/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib/cli-launcher/* org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
2024.02.02 21:09:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2024.02.02 21:09:10 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[8.11.0], pid[79], build[tar/d9ec3fa628c7b0ba3d25692e277ba26814820b20/2023-11-04T10:04:57.184859352Z], OS[Linux/5.15.0-1053-azure/amd64], JVM[Eclipse Adoptium/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/17.0.10/17.0.10+7]
2024.02.02 21:09:10 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM home [/opt/java/openjdk], using bundled JDK [false]
2024.02.02 21:09:10 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=org.elasticsearch.preallocate, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp, -XX:ErrorFile=/opt/sonarqube/logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:disable, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djna.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Dcom.redhat.fips=false, -Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=true, -Xmx2G, -Xms2G, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1073741824, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.distribution.type=tar, --module-path=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib, --add-modules=jdk.net, --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH, -Djdk.module.main=org.elasticsearch.server]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-core]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [old-lucene-versions]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [rest-root]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-redact]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-security]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [aggregations]
2024.02.02 21:09:12 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [apm]
2024.02.02 21:09:16 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt/sonarqube/data (/dev/root)]], net usable_space [93.5gb], net total_space [123.8gb], types [ext4]
2024.02.02 21:09:16 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [2gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2024.02.02 21:09:17 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [zquz6ZvuTjmIOZ26sO09rA], cluster name [sonarqube], roles [data_warm, master, remote_cluster_client, data, data_cold, ingest, data_frozen, ml, data_hot, transform, data_content]
2024.02.02 21:09:18 INFO  es[][o.e.x.s.Security] Security is disabled
2024.02.02 21:09:18 INFO  es[][o.e.t.n.NettyAllocator] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=elasticsearch_configured, chunk_size=1mb, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_netty_default_chunk_and_page_size=false, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb}]
2024.02.02 21:09:18 INFO  es[][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
2024.02.02 21:09:19 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [single-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]
2024.02.02 21:09:19 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
2024.02.02 21:09:19 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
2024.02.02 21:09:20 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:36911}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:36911}
2024.02.02 21:09:20 INFO  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] explicitly enforcing bootstrap checks
2024.02.02 21:09:20 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Elasticsearch] node validation exception
[1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [1] lines before starting Elasticsearch. For more information see [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.11/bootstrap-checks.html]
bootstrap check failure [1] of [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]; for more information see [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.11/_maximum_map_count_check.html]
ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /opt/sonarqube/logs/sonarqube.log
2024.02.02 21:09:20 WARN  es[][o.e.n.Node] unexpected exception while waiting for http server to close
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move to stopped state when not started
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.prepareForClose(Node.java:1776) ~[elasticsearch-8.11.0.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.shutdown(Elasticsearch.java:468) ~[elasticsearch-8.11.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move to stopped state when not started
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.Lifecycle.canMoveToStopped(Lifecycle.java:128) ~[elasticsearch-8.11.0.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.stop(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:73) ~[elasticsearch-8.11.0.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$prepareForClose$59(Node.java:1768) ~[elasticsearch-8.11.0.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        ... 1 more
2024.02.02 21:09:20 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopping ...
2024.02.02 21:09:20 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopped
2024.02.02 21:09:20 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closing ...
2024.02.02 21:09:20 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closed

ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly, with exit code 78
2024.02.02 21:09:20 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 78
2024.02.02 21:09:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2024.02.02 21:09:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

I am using using a yaml file with only the values instructed changed.

I'm expecting to be able to access the Sonarqube dashboard on port 9000 after resources are started.  Has anyone else encountered this?